# Running "zt" directly after opening a file in Vim

Tags: vim

When opening a file from the command line while simultaneously specifying a line to jump to, e.g. like this:

```
vim ./myfile +34
```

I also need to automatically scroll to the top as in doing `zt` command. I have tried doing something like this:

```
vim ./myfile +34 -c 'zt'
```

but it fails with:

```
Not an editor command: zt
```

Is there a way to accomplish this from command line? I'm using Vim 8.0 on RHEL 8.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is the "`normal`" command, which runs its arguments as if typed in normal mode (-c always runs commands as if they were typed on the :-command line):

```
vim ./myfile +34 -c 'normal zt'
```